# Print more than one image invisibly

Tags: c#

I have a folder with hundreds of photos. I want to send the photos to the printer at once. Print more than one numbered image within a folder invisibly Print .

I used this code, but it displays the files before printing. I want to print directly once invisibly., or choose the method and type of printer, and then print invisibly.

```
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\startup\Desktop\New folder");
  FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*.jpeg");

            foreach (FileInfo file in Files)

            {

                

                System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psiPrint = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();

                psiPrint.Verb = "print";

                psiPrint.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

                psiPrint.FileName = file.FullName;

                psiPrint.UseShellExecute = true;

                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(psiPrint);

            }
```

Comment: You're calling the default image viewer, to have silent printing you need to find an image viewer that has silent printing mode and explicitly call it.

Comment: `invisibly` so you want to print a blank sheet of paper?

Comment: so you want to print a blank sheet of paper? No, this is for photographic research papers sent to the printing press, and I do not want to display them. I want direct, invisible printing of photos.  THANKS Rand Random,Martheen

Comment: @fast2021 Have you tried using the `PrintDocument` class?

Comment: ave you tried using the PrintDocument class?  I don't know how to do it because I work with crystal reports?